# qrtz_blob_triggers Table Creation Error

Tags: oracle, quartz-scheduler

I am receiving a "missing right parenthesis" error when I try running the script provided by Quartz to create tables. All of the other tables are created without any issues. Here is the command that is throwing the error:

```
CREATE TABLE qrtz_blob_triggers
(
SCHED_NAME VARCHAR2(120) NOT NULL,
TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
BLOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
CONSTRAINT QRTZ_BLOB_TRIG_PK PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
CONSTRAINT QRTZ_ BLOB_TRIG_TO_TRIG_FK FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP) 
    REFERENCES QRTZ_TRIGGERS(SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP)
);
```

Has anyone run into this error before? I can normally catch a "missing right parenthesis" error, but this one has me stumped. BTW, the error is pointing to the space between FOREIGN and KEY.

Comment: Is that space in `QRTZ_ BLOB_TRIG_TO_TRIG_FK` also present in your code in production?  Or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: That was it! The file wasn't edited, so it must be a problem with the downloaded archive.